# Mat-sort with rxjs is not working properly

Tags: angular, sorting, rxjs, angular-material, angular5

I have the problem with implement mat-sort in mat-table, when source was created from observers stream.

Simply implementation it via documentation by:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

is not working properly - always will be sorted only 5 rows on my table.

I think, my problem is with the proper use it with rxjs connection.

Unfortunately, after checking another questions/documentation I can't find any idea.

I generated data source from two observer stream. Also I used for it BehaviourSubject (for initial values), combineLatest and switch map. Table was created properly and working perfectly.

Also when I added filter (according to angular material design documentation) is working properly. But mat-sort... not (only 5 first rows).

```js
    ngOnInit() {
            this.filters = itemFilters;
            this.idSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.filters[0]);
            Observable.combineLatest(this.name, this.selectedFilter)
                .do(_ => this.items = null)
                .switchMap(([name, filterIndex]: [Name | null, number]) => {
                    const item = this.filters[filterIndex];
                    this.namesSubject.next(item.display);
                    return this.itemService.getItems(name);
                })
                .subscribe(this.setItems.bind(this), this.setError.bind(this));
        }
```

Also I tried with Observable.zip - but I think it is also not my case. Any idea/advice will be very valuable.

I think, I should subscribe sorting method to observable streams. That same problem I have with pagination. Sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: I have that same issue. Connect two or more observables and using mat-table -> MatSort feature.

Comment: can you please provide some sort reproduceable code, e.g. in stackblitz

Comment: This is a fragment of a large part of the project. I will try to simulate similar behavior, I would only have to create a new project. But I will try.

Comment: I'd really like to answer this to help you out but the question isn't clear. Could you create a demo showing the problem?

Comment: It is not easy for me to write a small part of app that works on an open api. But I still try. In general - the problem is connecting multiple observer streamers and sorting them by mat-sort approach.

Comment: You don't need to use any api, just mock some responses in form of observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question code looks like the example from mat-tables that display data from HTTP calls: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmoxkmpkkyj?file=app%2Ftable-http-example.ts

I think the implementation can be simplified by handling the pagination and sorting events separately.

Please take a look at this example I build that refreshes the data on each event: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-table-sort-merge-streams?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-books%2Fmy-books.component.ts

The Event handlers

```
ngOnInit() {

    // default data 
    this.refresh(this.getDefaultOptions());

    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe((sort: Sort) => {
      console.log('sortChange', this.sort.active);
      this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
      this.refresh(this.getCurrentOptions());
    });

    this.paginator.page.subscribe((page: PageEvent) => {
      console.log('paginator ', page);
      this.refresh(this.getCurrentOptions());
    });

}
```

The method to get the current view options

```
getCurrentOptions() {
    const options: ViewOptions = {
      sortField: this.sort.active,
      sortDirection: this.sort.direction,
      page: this.paginator.pageIndex,
      pageSize: this.paginator.pageSize
    };

    return options;
  }
```

An example of how to merge multiple streams

```
  findBooks(options: ViewOptions): Observable<BooksResponse> {

    console.log('findBooks', options);

    // retrieve multiple streams
    const multipleStreams = this.mockMultipleStreams();

    // sort and slice result
    const sortedAndSliced = multipleStreams.pipe(
      tap(items => {
        items = items.sort((a, b) => {
          const sortOrder = options.sortDirection === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
          const valueA = a[options.sortField];
          const valueB = b[options.sortField];

          var result = (valueA < valueB) ? -1 : (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : 0;
          return result * sortOrder;
        });
      }),
      tap((items: Book[]) => {
        const start = options.page * options.pageSize;
        const end = start + options.pageSize;
        items = items.slice(start, end);
      })
    );

    // wrap in the response object
    const bookResponse = sortedAndSliced.pipe(
      map((items: Book[]) => {
        const response: BooksResponse = {
          items: items,
          total: this.fakeDataLength
        };
        return response;
      })
    );

    return bookResponse;

  }

  mockMultipleStreams(): Observable<Book[]> {
    const third = this.fakeDataLength / 3;

    // merge all the streams together
    const allTheBooks: Observable<[Book[], Book[], Book[]]> = zip(
      of(this.mockBooks('Magazine', third)),
      of(this.mockBooks('Books', third)),
      of(this.mockBooks('Newspaper', third))
    );

    // flatten the data 
    const result = allTheBooks
      .pipe(map((items) => {
        let result: Book[] = [];
        items.forEach(books => {
          books.forEach(book => { result.push(book) })
        });
        return result;
      }));

      return result;
  }
```

See the full code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-table-sort-merge-streams?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks.service.ts

Comment: Thank You for response. I think that solution is not working for me. I mean, where I have multiple streams.

Comment: You should combine the multiple streams at the service level

Comment: I will add an example

Comment: updated the response with multiple streams, take a look

Comment: Still dont work. I think, there is a problem with `combineLatest`. Still was sorted only few rows in the table.

Comment: I would add console.log in each operation, that would tell you where tje issue is, I like to split the observables in variables as well that helps tp understand the steps as well